# Using a field value from the active record object being saved in a custom validation message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

I'm having trouble figuring out if this is possible or not (Google is not my friend tonight).   I have this validation (for @product.save):

```
validates_uniqueness_of :product_name, :scope => [:category, :catalog_id], :message => "..."
```

I'd like the error message to name the category to be clear.  Like, say :category in this case is 'shoes'.

What I'd like is to have the error say:

```
"There is already a shoes product in this catalog with the same name."
```

For example, I've tried:

```
:message => "There is already a #{:category} product in this catalog with the same name."
```

(result: "There is already a category product in this catalog with the same name.")

and

```
:message => "There is already a #{@product.catalog} product in this catalog with the same name."
```

(result: nil error)

Answer (score 1):

Try (not tested, but one of them should work):

```
:message => "There is already a %{category} product ..."
:message => "There is already a %{value} product ..."
:message => "There is already a %{attribute} product ..."
```

If that does not work, move the message into a translation file (`config/locales/en.yml` for example) and the use `t()` to get the message.

Comment: :message => "There is already a %{value} product ..." should work.

Answer (score 1):

Validation messages by default use the [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) api which does support interpolations.

However it can only interpolate values passed to it by the validator so the only way you can do it is by hacking the [UniquenessValidator](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/UniquenessValidator/validate_each) to pass it in as an option.

Comment: Yeah I didn't have any luck inserting an Class instance variable inside the message either.   Of course, being specific like I was trying is only to benifit the user (assuming they aren't smart enough to understad "another product of the same category already exists in this catalog with the same name"). Thanks!